# InsertDE to UpsertDE Syntax changes help

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I am not fully confident with my dev abilities and am attempting to change some code to populate a DE with UpsertDE logic instead of InsertDE.

I have the following being used for InsertDE, and need the same values with the UpsertDE but have been instructed the syntax between the two are different. Any assistance on getting the proper syntax in place for UpsertDE is appreciated!

```
%%[
InsertDE("Message Log", "SubscriberKey", _subscriberkey, "EmailAddress", emailaddr_, "DateSent", Now(), "MessageType", "Email", "MessageId", _emailid, "MessageText", @VAWP, "Subject", @subjectline, "JobID", _jobid, "Message_Log_ID", @message_log_id, "PreHeader", @preheader)
]%%
```

Comment: Just follow instructions for UpsertDE function [here](https://ampscript.guide/updatede/). You can find other functions there as well, including InsertDE for your comparison.

Comment: This syntax seems to be in order, however is failing to deliver the expected result: upsertde("Message Log", 1, "Message_Log_ID", @message_log_id, "SubscriberKey",_subscriberkey,"EmailAddress",emailaddr_,"DateSent",Now(),"MessageType","Email","MessageId",_emailid,"MessageText",@VAWP,"Subject",@subjectline,"JobID",_jobid,"PreHeader",@preheader)

Comment: Hey @kalamb. From a quick look you may want to change `subscriberkey` to `_subscriberkey` and `_jobid` to `jobid`, unless you have subscriberkey and _jobid in the sendable DE. See [Personalization Strings in Email Studio](http://https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5)  for more info

Comment: If that still doesn't work, can you tell me what is/are the selection argument(s) and provide a list of all the field names in the DE you are writing to?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I was able to get it to work!